# Distance between 2 System.Drawing.Point

Tags: math, distance

How can I find the distance between 2 System.Drawing.Point?

I googled and didn't find it...

```
Dim p1 As New Point(0, 10)
Dim p2 As New Point(10, 10)
Dim distance = ??
```

In this case, it should be 10, but what about here?

```
Dim p1 As New Point(124, 942)
Dim p2 As New Point(34, 772)
Dim distance = ??
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you asking for the distance on screen (in relation to resolution) or simply the distance formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_formula#Geometry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Distance formula:
sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2 )

Comment: And high school students wonder when they are EVER going to need such information.

Comment: I am making my living right now (and a grand one, too) working on software that requires me to know this stuff. There is *NO* useless knowledge. Which is why I am interested in learning about just about everything in the world. Except golf. Not so much golf.

Answer (score 5):

```
Point p1 = new Point(7, 5);
Point p2 = new Point(26, 29);
double distance = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((p2.X - p1.X), 2) + Math.Pow((p2.Y - p1.Y), 2)), 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know where the formula that people are giving you comes from, this is generalized as [The Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
SquareRoot(Square(p1.x - p2.x)+Square(p1.y-p2.y))
```